# Why does tar allow unhyphenated options?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, tar, manpage

When reading through `man tar`, you will see that nowhere is the tar command used without a hyphen. Why then does tar allow the following two commands to be valid:

```
tar c .
tar -c .
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Why use superflous dash (-) to pass option flags to tar?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13573/why-use-superflous-dash-to-pass-option-flags-to-tar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 3.3 The Three Option Styles
>
> There are three styles for writing operations and options to the
> command line invoking tar. The different styles were developed at
> different times during the history of tar. These styles will be
> presented below, from the most recent to the oldest.

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Styles.html#Old-Options

Comment: I'm not sure what I expected. I guess "GNU tar supports old options not only for historical reasons," is as much as one could expect. Perhaps it was silly to think there would be a more interesting history worthy of note.

Comment: The link has moved to https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Styles.html#Old-Options (submitted as an edit to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I use linux mint distrib and see that part of `man tar` look as

```
SYNOPSIS
 tar [-] A --catenate --concatenate | c --create | d --diff --compare | --delete | r --append | t --list | --test-label |
     u --update | x --extract --get [options] [pathname ...]
```

So we see that the hyphen is optional. But we can use it.